# telerik jquery KendoTreeList is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to use the functionality of kendoTreeList through Jquery. The Tekerik Documentation is here:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist

The code I am using is shown below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.treelist.min.js")">
</script>

<script>
    var search = document.getElementById("SearchTerm");


function SearchResults(results) {
    $('#ResultsList').empty();

    var items = {};
    $.each(results, function (i, value) {
        items += { id: i, parentId: null, Name: value.MacroName, Type:"Macro" }
            if (value.Files.length > 0) {
               $.each(value.Files, function (x, File) {
                   items += {parentId: i, Name: File, Type:"File"}
                });
            }
            if (value.Servers.length > 0) {
                   $.each(value.Services, function (x, Server) {
                         items += { parentId: i, Name: Server, Type: "Server" }
                   });
               }
           if (value.Databases.length > 0) {
               $.each(value.Databases, function (x, DB) {
                    items += { parentId: i, Name: DB, Type: "Databases"}
               });
           }
           if (value.Services.length > 0) {
             $.each(value.Services, function (x, Service) {
                 items += { parentId: i, Name: Service, Type: "Service" }
              });
           }
           if (value.SecGroups.length > 0) {
             $.each(value.SecGroups, function (x, PSI) {
                 items += { parentId: i, Name: PSI, Type: "SecGroup" }
                });
          }


    });


    $("#ResultsList").kendoTreeList({
        columns: [
            { field: "Name" },
            { field: "Type"},
            {
            command: [{
            name: "Display",
            text: "Display",
            click: function (e) {
                // e.target is the DOM element representing the button
                var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
                // get the data bound to the current table row
                var data = this.dataItem(tr);
                console.log("Details for: " + data.Name);
                Display(data.Name, data.Type)
            }
        }]
            }
        ],
        editable: true,
        dataSource: items
    });
}
 function Display(value,Type)...
</script>
```

There is more code but search results is all that's necessary, and it contains the kendoTreeList function. the Debugger is saying .kendoTreeList is not a function, but it should. Why is it saying it is not a function?

Comment: When you add kendo.all, all widgets are already added, no need to add a single reference to treelist source. Also, double check in your console network tab if the file is being loaded properly.

Comment: Both load fine. Even if I drop the Kendo.All the KendoTreeList still fails @DontVoteMeDown with kendo.treelist loading properly

Comment: Where and when you call `SearchResults()` ?

Comment: after a AJAX post call on success that passes back a list of Objects that has a name then five lists in each object which is why I parse it in that manner.... That shouldnt effect if the function is found or not though  @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: You're right, it should not. Idk whats going on, Im sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused due to having more than one JQuery Script reference. 
When working in MVC the `_Layout` page under **Views->Shared->_Layout.cshtml** had a reference at the bottom to `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` by default. This needs to be removed. Having more than one Jquery reference will cause issues with the scripts causing the compiler to be unable to find the function you are trying to use.